# Export to PDF in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

This code below is used to export `grid data` to `PDF`. This Code is working fine for `.docx` and `.xls` extensions except `.pdf` ! Its actually unable to find the content type of file!

Can you help me to find the solution?

***CODE:***

```
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid grid =
            new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
            grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            grid.DataSource = ds;
            grid.DataBind();Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=abc.pdf");
            grid.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            grid.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
            Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
            Response.End();
```

Comment: try `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=abc.pdf");`

Comment: @CodingDefined that returns me unknown data type file